# Custom TextBox Control with built-in client-side validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, custom-controls

I have a textbox in my application which has multiple validation on it e.g. RequiredFieldValidator, RegexValidation and CustomValidation. My page has several similar textboxes. So I just copy-paste and change id and controltovalidate properties and it is working.

Since similar tbxs are going to be used on another page as well, I think it would be nice to create my own custom TextBox control with built-in validation.

Here are two approaches I have found and tried:

1: Implement from IValidator perform my custom validation in Validate Method.  As shown here: [Self-Validating TextBox](http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=27&skatID=217&artID=5691) But it does not show how to implement client-side validation.

2: Create custom control that derives from TextBox and add asp.net built-in validators I need. As shown here:[Custom TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302252/custom-textbox-with-built-in-validator-server-side-validation-not-firing). I tried the code and it works server/client side.

I like the first approach but don't know how to implement client-side validation. I know I need a client-side js function. I can do that. I know how to include my js file using Page.ClientScript class but don't know how to integrate all together and make it work.

I can create a UserControl or the second approach above but for now I am specifically looking to learn and implement client-side validation from custom control.

I am using Asp.Net 2.0. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're right, you can always implement your custom server control that derives from TextBox and automatically associates a couple of validators. But usually you won't create custom controls as far as it is not explicitly needed and then through several different projects. For having *client-side* validaton you usually need JavaScript, but note that most of the ASP.net validation controls have their client-side validation already built-in (i.e. required field validators, range validators,...). Others (like the custom validator) allow to hook in your custom javascript.

An approach that sounds more reasonable to me is to have your TextBox controls as they are on your ASP.net page/usercontrol and to associate the validators from your  code dynamically at runtime. Say in your `OnInit` event, you call a function `RegisterRequiredValidators` passing in a list of TextBoxes. I'm just thinking aloud:

```
public override void OnInit(...)
{
   ...
   RegisterRequiredValidators(
      txtFirstname, 
      txtSurname, 
      txtAge
   }
   ...
}

public void RegisterRequiredValidators(params Control[] textBoxes)
{
   //execute the logic of creating and attaching validators
}
```

That's just a stupid example, just to explain the context. In theory you can evolve this concept to register any kind of validators. We do something similar at work, by abstracting this in form of "rules" which ultimately are being rendered as ASP.net validators on the front-end.

Comment: Thanks Juri. Yes, I am aware of client-side validation that comes with built-in validators and that's how the 2nd approach I mentioned works. I will be using this control several times on more than one page and potentially in other projects as well. I doubt the approach you suggested will fit my needs. If I can't make 1st approach to work, I think I'll go with 2nd one.